# jQuery reset toggle state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `toggle` on a button like so:

```
$('#button123').toggle(function() {
        $("#button123").text("-");

        $("#slideDiv").slideDown( "fast", function() {

        });
}, function() {
        $("#button123").text("+");

        $("#slideDiv").slideUp( "fast", function() {

        });
});
```

Further down in my code I want to "reset" the toggle state. and make `slideDiv` slide back up.

Currently I am trying to do that by:

```
    $("#button123").text("+");

    $("#slideDiv").slideUp("fast", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
```

The problem is that after running that code I have to press `button123` twice for the toggle to work again. I'm assuming this is because I somehow need to reset it?

Any ideas?

Comment: could you out this code in a fiddle and then post it?

Comment: Since this use of `.toggle()` has been removed from recent versions of jQuery, you probably should just rewrite it completely. Use your own variable to keep track of the state, and then you can easily reset it.

Comment: The problem is since you are updating the state outside of `toggle` the plugin does not know about the change and it try to execute the change again... that is why your toggle is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle function uses an internal mechanism to determine which of the 2 callbacks to be executed. So assuming it is an incremental counter where if the value if the value is odd then the first callback else the second callback is executed, when you update the text and display of the elements outside of the toggle handlers the internal counter is not executed. So `toggle` does not know about the fact that the text is changed to `+` which will result in toggle calling the second handler(if in the previous click handler one was executed).

One possible solution is to use a click based solution instead of toggle(another reason is toggle was removed in 1.9)

```
$('#button123').click(function () {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    $(this).text(text == "-" ? '+' : '-');
    if (text == '-') {
        $("#slideDiv").slideUp("fast", function () {});
    } else {
        $("#slideDiv").slideDown("fast", function () {});
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ew7fo7qk/)